# How to update timestamp values in column by adding a specific time (seconds) to the existing timestamp using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, phpmyadmin

I am using mysql and pma. I have a table `mytable` and a column `time`, storing ~17K individual values, i.e. timestamps (integers).

I need to update each by adding `962758` to each timestamp. What does the SQL command for that look like?

```
SELECT (*) FROM `mytable` t1
UPDATE `mytable` SET time = + 962758
PROFIT? :)
```

Would you need a `SELECT` statement for that or does it work with `UPDATE` only?

I cant use php for that in this case.

Comment: What's the datatype of that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that it's `TIMESTAMP` datatype, you can say

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET time = time + INTERVAL 962758 seconds;
```

Per your comment, since it's of `INT` type; you can just do the addition likewise you are already doing.

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `time` = `time` + 962758;
```

Comment: its int - would also work with that? or is timestamp == int datatype?

Comment: `time = time +` is the second `time` a placeholder for the actual time value in each row?

Comment: @Alex, it's nothing but saying `a = a + b` ... first the addition will happen and then assignment.

Comment: I see that, I'm just wondering whether it does that for each row individually

Comment: Yes Alex. Unless you include a `where` clausule will afect all rows in the table. And looks like you should look for a basic sql tutorial first so you get the tools to understand how sql works

Comment: @Rahul thanks a lot, worked perfectly :) i am very new to sql yes, maybe i should! it really seems like a super fast and powerful "language"

Answer (score 1):

If the data is stored as a `datetime` value, then you simply can use:

```
select timestampadd(second, 962758, time)
```

If the value is a unix timestamp, then it is already in seconds, and you can just add 962758.

Comment: would you be so kind and provide a fully runnable sql command?

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment the field is int

```
 UPDATE `mytable` 
 SET time = time + 962758;
```

And no need select